# File input returning a null value ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a begin form on a view that contains a file input, but when I try pass the input value to my controller action it returns a null value.

Code in view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoCreate", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label>Description:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Description", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", required = "required" });
    <label>Price:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Price", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", required = "required" });
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Quantity", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", required = "required" });
    <label>Image:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Image", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file", required = "required" });
    <label>Product Type:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", new SelectList(Model, "ID", "TypeName"), "Select Product Type", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" });

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add to Table</button>
}
```

Code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoCreate(string Description, float Price, int Quantity, HttpPostedFileBase Image, int TypeID)
{
    return View();
}
```

If insert a breakpoint by the action, all the other variables have the correct values but the Image returns null, I am not sure why this is, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add attribute in form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this

You need to just add `htmlAttribute` in form `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoCreate", "Admin", FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label>Description:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Description", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", required = "required" });
    <label>Price:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Price", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", required = "required" });
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Quantity", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", required = "required" });
    <label>Image:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Image", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file", required = "required" });
    <label>Product Type:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", new SelectList(Model, "ID", "TypeName"), "Select Product Type", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" });

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add to Table</button>
}
```